# Getting/filtering certain text from a line from text file

Tags: regex, text, filter

I have text file with all the IPs of all my players, I am trying to make a whitelist for my server

the problem is there more info on the line as well

each line looks like this:

```
L 12/21/2014 - 23:20:00: [sm_allinfo_v2.1.1.smx] .:[Name: somename | STEAMID: STEAM_1:1:10101010 | IP: 111.111.00.00]:.
```

I want to only the 111.111.00.00 (IP part), so in the file each line is just an ip

i'm not sure if this can be done with notepad++, can someone write a script cuz i'm very inexperienced with this

Comment: Try this regex to match ips https://regex101.com/r/yJ8fM8/1

Comment: try the start point as `|IP:` and count till end you will get the result

Comment: I can't give you code without knowing your environment. What language do you know already, what platform are you running on, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex that works for me:

```
/.*IP\:\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/
```

Test it in [here](https://regex101.com/r/fI2oP7/1).

Implemented in PHP:

```
// define $string_read_from_file before this
preg_match_all("#.*IP\:\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)#", $string_read_from_file, $matches);
foreach($matches[1] as $match)
    echo $match . "<br>"; // priting all the matched IPs
```